# Копирование ссылки в память из dataGridView

Tags: c#

Есть dataGridView, в котором выведена БД. Хочу, чтобы при двойном щелчке по ячейке открывалось изображение, которое хранится как ссылка в ячейке. Имею код:

```
    private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var link = dataGridView1.SelectedCells;
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(link);
    }
```

Возникает ошибка:
Ошибка  2   Аргумент "1": преобразование типа из "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection" в "string" невозможно

Подскажите, как правильно написать код.

Попробовал ещё один вартант:

```
 string p = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString());
         pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
         pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(p);
```

Также не работает.

Comment: Экземпляры какого класса находятся в коллекции `dataGridView1.SelectedCells`? Какие там есть поля?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо события двойного клика по всему гриду, следует использовать событие двойного клика по конкретной ячейке.

```
private void DataGridView_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) // индекс колонки с линком
    {
        var link = dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        //pictureBox.Load(link);
        //pictureBox.LoadAsync(link);
    }
}
```

Если значение в ячейке является валидным url'ом, его можно просто передать в метод `Load` пикчабокса (или `LoadAsync`, если загрузка будет долгой, например, из интернета).

Comment: Что то я не понял, как предложенный код решает проблему автора? Он ничего же не откроет, ничего не покажет

Comment: @tym32167 - если в ячейке линк на картинку (а судя по другим вопросам автора, это именно так), то PictureBox сам загрузит и покажет изображение.

Comment: понял, я просто сперва не обратил внимание не закомменченый код

Comment: Cпасибо! Ссылку получил таким образом. Только изображение не выводится таким способом, получилось вывести его с помощью:

Comment: pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(link);